# Invoke PowerShell script to create Office 365 user from workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We have a PowerShell script to create Office 365 users, which creates the user and then does all the Exchange Online admin, putting them in the right Distribution groups, sharing their calendars, setting their time zones etc. etc.

Would it be possible to trigger this script from a SharePoint Online workflow, such that it runs when a hiring manager creates an item in a 'New User Request' list?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. Exist only one way do it, it's write  your custom web service and call it from workflow.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions) allows you to run PowerShell scripts and trigger through a HTTP call.